# Transfer Data Between two hierarchical fragments inside activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have A Navigation Drawer with list of items , and on click on a list item opens 
another list of events(with A custom list adapter)[1 st fragment].

And a click on any of any of that list item i  want to open a fragment which displays its details[2 st fragment] .

So i want to transfer position of item click from 1st frag to 2 nd frag , 
i have static data in 2 nd  frag , how do i transfer that position ?

I tried with interface ,
 but with every time i do anything i get error in logcat as 1st fragment is not attached to Main activity .

And i have created layout(and referred them as fragment) and there is NO  so  no Id to get in mainactivity in 'getFragmentById' ? Thanks .

Comment: It is pretty neatly explained here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html. If you want a specific solution, share your code.

Comment: i deleted all of that code and i am gonna  write again...if i get error again i'll post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass data in `constructor` of fragment

```
FragmentManager fm = SliderActivity.this
                .getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment(your_data);
ft.replace(R.id.content_fragment, fragment, getResources()
                .getString(R.string.homeText));
ft.commit();
```

in `HomeFragment` set the value from `constructor`

```
HomeFragment(String value){
   this.value=value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getActivity()` from a fragment to find the `FragmentActivity` in which the fragment resides.
Then you can use `FragmentActivity.findFragmentByTag()` to find the other fragment in this `Actvity`. `